# .htaccess redirect root to i18n content

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm facing problem with `.htaccess` and have not idea how to solve it.

Our webpage is exposed on two domains: `example.de` and `example.com`.

I would like to redirect user to i18n content when user request root:

- `https://example.com/` URL should be redirected to `https://example.com/en`
- `https://example.de/` URL should be redirected to `https://example.de/de`

There should be no redirect when user requests i18n content e.g.:

- `https://example.com/es/***` URL should be redirected to `https://example.com/es/***`
- `https://example.de/es/***` URL should be redirected to `https://example.de/es/***`

Can anyone help?

Comment: What about `https://example.com/<foo>` (and `example.de/<foo>`)? No redirect? "to `https://example.com/en`" - I assume the target URL should have a trailing slash? Is `/en` a physical directory?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect only the document root of the respective domains then you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "example.com/" to "example.com/en"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule ^$ /en [R=302,L]

# Redirect "example.de/" to "example.de/de"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.de
RewriteRule ^$ /de [R=302,L]
```

This assumes you have already canonicalised the hostname (ie. no `www` subdomain).

As per your example, I have omitted the trailing slash on the target URL-path (eg. `/en`). However, if `/en` (and `/de`) are physical subdirectories then you *must* include the trailing slash, otherwise mod_dir will trigger a secondary 301 (permanent) redirect to append the trailing slash.

The regex `^$` - matches the document root only (an empty URL-path). The *CondPattern* `=example.com` is an exact match string comparison (not a regex) that matches against the `Host` HTTP request header.

Note also that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Language redirects generally should be "temporary", allowing the user to change the language. However, if this is intended to be *permanent*, then change it to a 301, but only once you have confirmed that it's working as intended.